# jenkins valgrind executable options missing

Tags: jenkins, command-line-arguments, valgrind, executable

I've got a jenkins CI installed with the [valgrind plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Valgrind+Plugin). There is one very important thing missing there: you cannot set executable options. I can set parameters, but if I want to call `valgrind my_executable -opt my_option_value` the plugin will generate the command `valgrind my_executable "-opt my_option_value"` and this is useless.

I found a [jira ticket](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-15138) corresponding to this feature. It's stated to be fixed since version 0.12, but I can't see neither in my jenkins (latest version - 1.500 and valgrind plugin 0.18) nor on the main plugin website screenshot.

Does anyone know if the valgrind jenkins plugin supports executable options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem solution is quite obvious - it's just a valgrind plugin bug (it dumps valgring executable options in quotation mark, but it shouldn't). This bug will be fixed in the next release of the plugin (0.19) planned on the end of february this year. See comments on https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-15138 and https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-16123